# Struggling with local storage for a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm struggling with trying to develop a simple Chrome Extension for my "portfolio".

What I want to do is really simple. I think I can do it in two different ways!
First way:

- I have an input field into my popup.html. What I want to do is get the text prompted into this input field and save it into the storage. After that, into my contentScript, I want to read the text/field saved into the storage and use it for some JS logic.

So, basically this is the input from popup.html:

```
<input class="custom-input-script-length" type="text" name="custom" id="values-input"/>
```

This is a function that get as parameter the value from the input. It's declared/called inside my popup.js:

```
function saveValue(value) {
     if(value !== '') {
         chrome.storage.local.set({'valuesInput': value}, function() {
             console.log("Values saved!");
         })
     }
}
```

Now, I've tried many ways to read the value directly from the chrome tab (not from the extension, I've tried into the contentScript) but it never works, it will always return an "undefined".

How should I read that value?

What my extension must do it's just grab the entire responseHeader and search for a specific value from the toString (for example: cache-control). If it will find it it will just show the value into a new div added into the DOM, that's all.

Another solution could be send/read the entire responseHeader from the chrome tab from inside the popup but even in this way it never works. All I get is "undefined" or the responseHeader of the extension context...

Do you have any advice?

I'm usind the Manifest V3 and I already have the storage permissions added into it.

Thanks for everyone who will answer!

Comment: I tested both your storage set and get functions (from the earlier version of question). They worked as expected.  So the problem is mostly likely that your are trying to populate the input value before the page has completed loading. That was the only way I could reproduce the problem.  To fix, load your popup.js script at the bottom of the popup page or else wrap your initialization in a [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event.

Comment: Wait, maybe I've explained it very bad, I'm sorry!

What I'm trying to do is to pass a value from the popup (of the extension) to the page content of a normal Chrome page/tab (outside of the extension).

In that case it's works too? How did you get the value into the chrome page?

Btw, thanks for the answer!! :)

Comment: There's no [MCVE](/help/mcve) in the question (you didn't show the code in the content script, how you run the content script or how it's declared in manifest.json, how you pass the value), so it's still unclear what the problem is. Depending on what it actually is, a different/better solution may exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is a response to OP's question which is too long for a comment.*

The only way I could reproduce the problem was by trying to set the popup input value before the page had completed loading. The Chrome storage method calls worked as expected. To avoid problems, initialization code should be loaded at the end of the page or else wrapped in a [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event.

OP also asks how to pass the stored value between popup and content pages. And in this case the content page can read the value directly from storage, which is shared between the pages. The content page may also receive notifications when the value changes by using the [chrome.storage.onChanged](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#event-onChanged) event.

The relevant parts of the Chrome extension are shown below:

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Popup</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input class="custom-input-script-length" type="text" name="custom" id="values-input"/>
    <!-- script must load last -->
    <script src="scripts/popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
  let valuesInput = document.getElementById("values-input");

  valuesInput.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    chrome.storage.local.set({valuesInput: valuesInput.value});
  })

  chrome.storage.local.get('valuesInput', function(obj) {
      if(obj.valuesInput !== undefined && obj.valuesInput !== '') {
          valuesInput.value = obj.valuesInput;
      }else {
          console.log("input field can't be empty.");
      }
  });
```

**content.js**

```
let valuesInput = null;

chrome.storage.local.get('valuesInput', (result) => {
  console.log('storage.get', result);
  valuesInput = result.valuesInput;
})
```

Comment: Amazing Thanks for your comment! Now it's more clear to me!